# Tool for locating hex sequence in binary file

Tags: linux, search, binaryfiles

Is there a Linux tool out there that locates a bit sequence given in hexadecimal representation in a binary file no matter how those bits are aligned in the file?

Example: I want to locate the two byte long sequence `f2 40` in a binary file. The perfectly aligned representation `f2 40` can easily be found using `hd` and `grep`. But I also want to find `01 e4 80`, `d3 e4 81` or `ff e4 80` (which all include `f2 40` shifted by one bit to the left).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting task!

Here is a simple 1-line C++ filter that you can use:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (char ch; std::cin.get(ch); std::cout << std::bitset<8>(ch));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
cat file.bin | binfilter | grep '1111001001000000'
```

You might want to improve the filter to print address identifications (like `xxd` or `od` do for octal/dex dumps). Alternatively, you can do the matching in C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought of writing a simple script/tool myself. However, my question was if there already exists a tool for that purpose.

Comment: @MBober: I guess you have my answer :)

Comment: Let's keep this unanswered for a bit and see if anyone mentions an already existing tool. If not, I will accept your answer.